# Flask : TypeError, can't pass argument

Tags: python, web, flask, arguments

I'm having hard time when I make dynamic URI where I have to passing argument. I got type error message when I tried to passing one argument. It keeps saying I passed 0 arguments. I couldn't find the problem.

This is views.py

```
@app.route('/delete_todo/<int:todo_id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_todo(todo_id):
    if request.form['todo_id']:
        g.db.execute('''delete * from todo where todo_id = ?''',   request.form['todo_id'])
        g.db.commit()
        flash('Your message was deleted')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

template where supposed to passing argument

```
{% for todo in todo %}    
<form action="{{ url_for('delete_todo', todo_id=todo.todo_id) }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="todo_id" value="{{ todo.todo_id }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
 </form>
{% else %}  
{% endfor %}
```

This is error message.

```
TypeError
TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1994, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in  full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
Brought to you by DON'T PANIC, your friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
```

Comment: Why you pass parameters in URL when you use `POST` method?

Comment: Already you can have `todo_id` from `request.form['todo_id']` why using dynamic url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the todo_id is already sent by form, so you do not need to send it as paramater in url. Also do not forget to convert the string todo_id to int

```
@app.route('/delete_todo', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_todo():
    if request.form['todo_id']:
        g.db.execute('''delete * from todo where todo_id = ?''',int(request.form['todo_id']))
        g.db.commit()
        flash('Your message was deleted')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```